# Remove requirement of App Store password

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-appstore, password

For some reason, I messed up my iPad and now when ever I try to download an app I already purchased, I have to type in my Apple ID password where before hand I could download it straightaway. I don't have this problem on my iPhone and they both use the same account.

**Is there a way to fix this so updating an app or downloading a previously purchased app on iOS does not require a password?**

Also I set it so that the password requirement is 15 minutes and free apps do not require a password, but they seem to have absolutely no effect (Settings>iTunes & AppStore>Password Settings)

Comment: Is the Apple ID you are using a child Apple ID, for whatever reason? (Family Sharing)

Comment: It's resolved. I just resetted all settings, logged in once and I don't need the password anymore. But I'm still puzzled as to what caused the problem in the first place.

Comment: Ok. Why don't you answer your own question then, so that others can benefit from your solution?

Comment: Please See This Link https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204030

Comment: @Rajesh that doesn't help as I already stated the password requirement and the free app options do not work and that my iPad has no Touch ID. It's most likely a glitch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure as to what caused the problem but all you need to do is go to:

```
Settings>General>Reset>Reset All Settings
```

This will result in losing all the wifi passwords you connected to but you can just retype them. Then just update or download something (that's free of course like an already purchased app or an update), type in the password, cancel (unless you actually want to download it) and now you don't need your password anymore.